# SPSiteDataQuery filtered by lists ID returns empty datatable

Tags: spsitedataquery

When I am querying lists items via `SPSiteDataQuery` by `ServerTemplate`, it returns items:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"107\"/>";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>";
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>";
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\"/>";

DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

But when I replace Lists condition to `"<Lists><List ID=\"" + listId + "\" /></Lists>"` it returns empty datatable.

`listId` is correct, List exists in child site of web.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: According to the msdn article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists(v=office.14).aspx), you have done it right. Try to verify the 'listId' parameter, it should be the list Guid without '{' and '}'.

Comment: @KGahbiche I replaced Lists parameter to `"<Lists><List ID=\"" + lib.Id.ToString("D").ToUpper() + "\"/></Lists>"`. Result Lists string is: `"<Lists><List ID="9027A315-0B24-4278-BC54-8C6D6BBC8C85"/></Lists>"`. I've checked list, it has same id and there is one task in this list. But result is still empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On possible issue is with Null Values in the Title field. So try changing `ViewFields` as follows

```
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' Nullable='True'/>";
```

Comment: If it was the reason of my problem, first query with ServerTemplate condition should be empty too, but it returns valid data.

Comment: I've checked your solution and It works, but I don't understand why first request returns values with same fields... Thanks!

Comment: @Amal, Could you please explain us the problem and the solution ? Thanks.

Comment: @KGahbiche If I understand it right, Nullable attrubute should be set to True if some fields in result can be empty.

Comment: @KGahbiche If the field contains NULL values, then instead of Skipping it returns empty. This information I found based on my experience with `SPSiteDataQuery`

Comment: @Amal, thank you for your feedback, I really appreciated.